# Getting this error when trying to encrypt. java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA

Tags: java, android, firebase, cryptography, rsa

I'm using key pair generator to generate a public and private key. I want to store the public key on firebase. To do this i am using getModulus and getExponent and regenerating the public key later. When I regenerate the key I get the exact same Modulus and Exponent but I'm still getting this error when trying to encrypt.

```
//This is my cryptography class
public class Cryptography {

    public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        return pair;
    }
    public static String encrypt1(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        byte[] cipherText = encryptCipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String str = new String(cipherText, "UTF-8");

        return Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }
    public static String decrypt1(String cipherText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        byte[] bytes = android.util.Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Cipher decriptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decriptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return new String(decriptCipher.doFinal(bytes), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String sign(String plainText, PrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception {
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();

        return Base64.encodeToString(signature, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    }

    public static boolean verify(String plainText, String signature, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
        Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
        publicSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        byte[] signatureBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(signature, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return publicSignature.verify(signatureBytes);
    }
}




//Generate  keypair
    try {
      keyPair =  Cryptography.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          KeyFactory factory = null;
                    try {
                        factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    RSAPublicKeySpec pub = null;
                    RSAPrivateKeySpec priv = null;
                    try {
                         pub = factory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
                         Log.e("PublicKey", pub.getModulus() + "\n" + pub.getPublicExponent());
                         priv = factory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPrivate(), RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);
                    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
registerUser(display_name, email, password,Publicmod.toString(), Publicexpon.toString());


 // Retrieving the Modulus and Exponent and regenerating the publicKey

 String expo = getIntent().getStringExtra("expo");
        String mod = getIntent().getStringExtra("mod");
        Log.e("mod", mod);
        Log.e("expo", expo);

        BigInteger PublicExponent = new BigInteger(expo,16);
        BigInteger PublicMod = new BigInteger(mod,16);

        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(PublicMod, PublicExponent);
        KeyFactory fact = null;
        try {
            fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PublicKey pubKey = null;
        try {
            pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
            Log.e("Public Key", pubKey.toString());
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e("Public Key", pubKey.toString());
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Meaning: dont what you are doing to get to the error. Give us sample code (with example data) that **shows** us what happens. If your assumptions and explanations about the nature of your code would be accurate, you wouldnt be here wondering why there is a bug somewhere ...

Comment: You should base64-encode the raw bytes from the encryption operation. Converting that to a String before encoding is already lossy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Generate  keypair
        KeyPair keyPair = generateKeyPair();
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKeySpec pub = factory.getKeySpec(keyPair.getPublic(), RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
        BigInteger PublicExponent = pub.getPublicExponent();
        BigInteger PublicMod = pub.getModulus();

        RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(PublicMod, PublicExponent);

        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PublicKey pubKey = fact.generatePublic(keySpec);
        System.out.println("Success " + pubKey);
    }
```

Which printed "Success ...".

That means your error is the retrieval of the expo and mod.
They must not be equal to the same you used.

Also a few notes:

- Use a constant `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` instead of putting "UTF-8" in `getBytes`
- You don't need to put `new SecureRandom` when generating a `KeyPair`
- Don't create a String if you don't end up using it
- Don't retrieve data if you still have access to it